# Converting referenced product into product display node?

Tags: commerce, views

I have a content type of "Product of the week" where an admin will choose 3 products and save this, from here a view pulls in the following information:

FILTER CRITERIA:

- Content: Type (=Product of the Week)
- Content: Published (Yes)

FIELDS:

- (Hidden) User: Picture
- (Hidden) Content: Body
- (Hidden) User: First
- Name Global: Custom Text

Here is where it gets tricky. I need to pull in the following information grouped together:

- Product Image
- Product Title (Linked to go to the product display for the product)
- Formatted Price

No matter how I work it, I cannot figure out how to reliably get these fields. I can use a referenced product entity but this causes the link to reference the /admin/ page for the product, not the product display link.

I can create a separate view to get the product display information easily, but is it possible to then pull that into this table?